# Include matching rspamd rules in mail headers

Tags: spam, spam-filter, rspamd

Spamassassin has a feature to include the matching rules in the headers of mails flagged as spam, so one can see why the mail was classified as spam and possibly adjust or create mailbox filters that match in specific rules.

Can I configure rspamd to add a similar header? It doesn't have to match the spamassassin format, it just should contain the matching rules and possibly the scores generated by each rule.